# Google Play Billing Library is missing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-library

Im trying to implement this library on my Android Studio app

Nevermind, in "SDK Tools" this library is missing

I try to do the following -> implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.1.0'

Adding this to dependencies, it says me an error in this lane

What should I do ?

Thank you too much,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no `3.1.0` version, the last one is `3.0.1`

try to update the version to `implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.1'`

(Deleted message)

Comment: Sorry you are right, I missclicked

I will try this, I will update you asap

Thanks m8